# Generating Dynamic combobox in jsp

Tags: jsp, struts2

I am having feedback parameter in table and teachers name in another table. Parameter and teacher name will different for different class.
Based on parameter number and teachers number i want to generate combo box and want to fetch data in Action class and then save these values including teacher name and feedback parameter to DB.

jsp page is like

```
        teachers|Name1|Name2|Name3.......
        Param   |-------------------------------- 
        p1        box1 box2  box3 ..........
        p2        box1 box2  box3 ..........
        p3        box1 box2  box3 ..........   
        .
        . 
        .
        .
        .
        .
```

How to do this any example.

Comment: you question is not clear at all,can you clarify it

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can dynamically populate a Combobox like this:

```
<html>
  <select>
  <%
    for(int i=0;i<=10;i++){
    %>
      <option value="<%=i%>"><%=i%></option>
    <%
    }
  %>
  </select>
</html>
```

In order to do this using data from a database take alook at [Vlads Answer hier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6891832/395659), you will only have to implement the code in a routine which you call from inside each table cell you need a cobobox in.

Comment: Generally you don't use scriptlets.

Comment: Well there is no user input involved hier so its not a big issue, but generally you are right +1